# Chamar função Oracle no Laravel?

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-5.2

Fiz toda a configuração para conectar no Oracle, ele conecta, mas eu quero fazer uma consulta dentro de uma função, mas ele está dando a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
>       oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number (SQL: SELECT funcao(':login') FROM DUAL)

A consulta que estou tentando fazer é assim:

```
public function login()
{
    $login = Request::input('login');
    $var = DB::connection('oracle1')
        ->select("SELECT funcao(':login') FROM DUAL", 
                           array( "login" => $login));    
    return 'Resultado: '.$var;
}
```

Se tendo com interrogação (?)

```
DB::connection('oracle1')
        ->select("SELECT funcao('?') FROM DUAL", 
                           array( "login" => $login));
```

A mensagem dá uma pequena mudada:

> oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number (SQL: SELECT funcao('CARLOS.BRITO') FROM DUAL)

Comment: Tentou fazer a consulta sem as apas simples no placeholder (`login` ou `?`)?

Comment: Mesma mensagem.

Comment: `DB::connection('oracle1')->select("SELECT funcao(?) FROM DUAL", array($login));` ou `DB::connection('oracle1')->select("SELECT funcao(:login) FROM DUAL", array(":login" => $login));` dá o mesmo erro?

Comment: Sim, só mudava que um vinha com o login informado e outro com o parametro apenas, mas descobri! No array, informei apenas a variável e deu certo ficando assim: `...select("SELECT funcao(?)  FROM DUAL", array( $login )`

Comment: @adventistaam se pode colocar o seu comentário como resposta da sua própria pergunta, depois assinale como resposta é bom fazer isso para sua pergunta ter uma resposta. tudo bem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o problema:

Mudei

```
->select("SELECT funcao(':login') FROM DUAL", 
                           array( "login" => $login));
```

Para

```
->select("SELECT funcao(':login') FROM DUAL", 
                           array( $login));
```

Ficando assim:

```
public function login()
{
    $login = Request::input('login');
    $var = DB::connection('oracle1')
        ->select("SELECT funcao(':login') FROM DUAL", 
                           array( $login));    
    return 'Resultado: '.$var;
}
```

Ai deu certo.

Obrigado aos que se dispuseram a me ajudar.